# How to find the smallest difference between two numbers in array without changing the order so that their difference is positive?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am given a harvest in tons according to the year. 
like {3,6,12,1,20,25} . 
find the smallest difference in harvest between the harvest of ordered years.
For given example difference is 2 because 3 - 1 = 2. Preserve order and result is positive
Sorting doesn't apply because numbers already sorted according to the years.
One way is to find all positive differences between elments and choose the smallest one.
But it takes O(n^2).
Is there any faster way to do it?
Main task is to find the minimum difference between elements in array without changing the order of elements so that their difference is positive.

Comment: I think you must be misunderstanding the word "consecutive". Either your description is incorrect, or your understanding of it is.

Comment: 3 and 1 are not consecutive in your example. The question is incosnistent.

Comment: I will improve.

Comment: The question is correct I guess. Stop downvoting

Comment: Do you just need a pair of elements with the smallest absolute value  of difference?

Comment: Difference has to be positive.

Comment: Could you please provide a precise definition of what you need to compute? Something like the maximum/minimum value of some function for all i and j such that i != j and some condition on a[i] and a[j] is satisfied. I do not fully understand the question.

Comment: @kraskevich I edited question.Is it understandable now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of the question, we need to compute `min(a[i] - a[j])` among all valid `i` and `j` such that `i < j` and `a[i] > a[j]`.

You can iterate over the array from left to right and keep all elements in a data structure that supports the `insert` and `upper_bound` operations efficiently (for example, an `std::set` in C++ or a `TreeSet` in Java).

The pseudo code (C++ like) may look like this:

```
s = empty set
res = INF
for elem in array: // from left to right
     if s.upper_bound(elem) != s.end(): // checks if there is a larger element
          res = min(res, *s.upper_bound(elem) - elem)
     s.insert(elem)
```

The insert and upper_bound operations take `O(log N)` time, so the total time complexity is `O(N log N)`.

Comment: It worked! I didn't know that treeSet keeps elements ordered.

Comment: @skrtbhtngr I thinks it's self-explanatory. We just iterate over all elements from left to right, find the smallest element we have already seen larger than the given one using a standard library data structure and add the new element to this structure.

Answer (score -1):

If you compare every value with every other value, it would be O(n^2).
So a possible answer could be to take the values in an auxillary array, sort it in O(n*ln(n)) and then in one traversal find minimum consecutive differences.
I couldn't figure out a O(n) solution. ( There could be one if some constraints are given on input data).